# how to show full EditText after appearing Keyboad in android?

Tags: android, layout

friends,

i am using following layout and tring to enter text and then saving the data but facing one problem when i click on EditText to type something.

keyboard appears and covers half of layout of EditText and button.
but when i type in it it shows completely.before typing in it keyboard covers half of Edittext layout.

can any one guide me how to show whole textbox with button after appearence of keyboard?

any help would be appriciated.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/LayoutReply"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#ffcc33"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:paddingBottom="50px"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"  

>

    <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:hint="Please enter text to reply!"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:maxLength="160"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ></EditText>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnPostReply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Message_Reply"></Button>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) and then experiment with the `android:windowSoftInputMode` values to get what you want.

Comment: Link given above doesn't exist anymore, can you please update it or provide link which contains very similar material?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not in the layout, but in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Make sure you update your activity and remove

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and add the below to your activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

My layout is below, but it is irrelevant to the fix

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextBug"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:height="150dp"
    android:hint="@string/reportBug"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submitBug" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

and in Activity

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
myscrollView.arrowScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```